# Como remover incremento de KmlLayers no Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

Tenho uma lista de itens (no código abaixo dois botões) no qual ao clicar em cada um e abre um modal com um mapa com seu determinado KML. Quando é clicado no primeiro item, aparece o polígono referente ao item, porém quando é clicado no próximo item, abre o polígono do primeiro item e do segundo no qual foi clicado. Creio que o que está acontecendo é um incremento de *Layers* no mapa, no qual não quero que aconteça. Vejam:

```js
var map;        
function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap);

$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  resizeMap($(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
  //resizeMap();
})

function resizeMap(kml) {
  if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
  setTimeout( function(){
    resizingMap(kml);
  } , 400);
}
function resizingMap(kml) {       
  if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: kml,
          map: map
        });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
        <a href="#" data-href='https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/stilldev/kmls/1494082535.KML' class="btn btn-lg btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal">Add 1</a>
      <a href="#" data-href='http://stilldev.s3.amazonaws.com/kmls/1494088425.KML' class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal">Add 2</a>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal" tabindex='-1'>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title">Mapa</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDfXgMUO82be1sHgJlXHdg4JkTgN7qtm-M&callback=initMap"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Como posso remover incremento de KmlLayers no Google Maps, mostrando um polígono de cada vez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A única alteração que fiz foi definir a variável `ctaLayer` de forma global e, antes de definir a nova *layer*, limpar o mapa da mesma com `ctaLayer.setMap(null)`, assim, se houver *layers* anteriores, ele exclui. Para garantir que `ctaLayer` possua o método `setMap` na primeira execução, eu iniciei ela junto com `map`, passando `null` como parâmetro.

```js
var map, ctaLayer;

function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
  ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(null);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap);

$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  resizeMap($(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
  //resizeMap();
})

function resizeMap(kml) {
  if (typeof map == "undefined") return;
  setTimeout(function() {
    resizingMap(kml);
  }, 400);
}

function resizingMap(kml) {
  if (typeof map == "undefined") return;
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

  ctaLayer.setMap(null);
  ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: kml,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <a href="#" data-href='https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/stilldev/kmls/1494082535.KML' class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal">Add 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-href='http://stilldev.s3.amazonaws.com/kmls/1494088425.KML' class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal">Add 2</a>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal" tabindex='-1'>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Mapa</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDfXgMUO82be1sHgJlXHdg4JkTgN7qtm-M" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> Também removi a parte `&callback=initMap` da URL da API do Google Maps que gerava um erro aqui, visto que a função `initMap` não está implementada.